# Image does not change into another image when mouse hovers over it?

Tags: image, hover, mouseover

I have an image and I want it to change its source when the mouse hovers over it. It isn't working with the code that I currently have.

```
#logo {
height: 15em;
width: 15em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -2.5em
}

#logo:hover {
content: url('C:\Users\haines\Desktop\Logo Hover.png');
height: 15em;
width: 15em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -2.5em
}
```

And the HTML code:

`<img id = "logo" src = "C:\Users\haines\Desktop\Logo.png" />`

Comment: You cannot change the `src` of an `img` element using CSS. You can use Javascript to do that, or use a background image instead of the `img` (which would be a bad idea if your image is content, not decoration, in that case you have to use Javascript to solve your problem).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a background image for logo to change when hover over it. Don't use img tag in html to set first log img.

```
#logo { 
    content: url("C:\Users\haines\Desktop\Logo.png"); 
}
```

Also, instead of content, I'd use background, like so

```
#logo { 
    background: url("C:\Users\haines\Desktop\Logo.png"); 
}
```

and same for your #logo:hover

Answer (score 0):

Using an image tag is maybe not the best style to do this. I would recommend something like this.
In your HTML File

```
<div class="myImage"></div>
```

and in your CSS File you could use this

```
.myImage { background: url(images/logo.png); width: 200px; height: 200px;}
.myImage:hover { background: url(images/logoHoverState.png); }
```

and you should use classes instead of referencing to IDs. This makes your code more recycleable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could switch the src value on hover if you want the logo in a img tag. . .

JavaScript / Jquery

```
var LogoSwap = function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var new = $this.data('hover');
    $this.data('hover', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', new);
}

$(function() {
  $('img#logo').hover(LogoSwap, LogoSwap);
});
```

HTML

```
<img id="logo" src="C:\Users\haines\Desktop\Logo.png" data-hover="C:\Users\haines\Desktop\LogoHover.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly change the source of an image with just HTML and CSS. However there are a few different ways to create a simple image rollover that suits your needs:

**1: You would be able to do it if you wrap the image in a div, and then have the image dissapear on hover showing a background image:**

HTML:

```
    <div class="image">  
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250/ffffff/000000">  
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {  
    width: 250px;   
height: 250px;  
    background: url('http://placehold.it/250/000000/ffffff');  
}  
.image:hover img {
    display: none;
}
```

**2: If the background approach is doable then just swapping the background images might be a solution:**

HTML:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
width: 250px; 
height: 250px;
background: url('http://placehold.it/250/000000/ffffff');
}  
.image:hover {
background: url('http://placehold.it/250/000000/ffffff');   
http://placehold.it/250/ffffff/000000
}
```

**3: If you insist on directly changing the source of the image, I suggest looking into a simple JavaScript approach:**

HTML:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/250/ffffff/000000" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);">
```

JS:

```
function hover(element) {
element.setAttribute('src', 'http://placehold.it/250/000000/ffffff');
}  
function unhover(element) {
element.setAttribute('src', 'http://placehold.it/250/ffffff/000000');
}
```